# MATLAB array rows arrangement

Tags: matlab, matrix

I work with Matlab and I have a transformation result which is a matrix (A) 4x4, for example:

```
A = [
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
    etc...
    ]
```

Is there any way to arrange the second row of A after its first row, so that the result would become:

```
A = [
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 etc... ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `vector = A(:)` after your first transformation. This will make a column vector, which you can transpose if you want a row vector.

For more control, try the [reshape command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). For instance, `vector = reshape(A,1,[])` should do the same as the above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on the question, but here's what I understand:
You want to take any size matrices and make a single row matrix

```
>> a = [1:4;5:8;9:12;13:16];
>> b = a.';
>> b(:).'

ans =  

 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

Comment: the `'` operator is the same as the Transpose function, as far as I know the return cannot be manipulated further, hence the need for `b`

Comment: Just for completeness, the `'` operator is for *conjugate* transpose, whereas the `.'` operator is for regular transpose. It's imperative to know the difference and to make a habit of always using the right one for your case.